# Rambam and Mitzvah of Ner Channukah (Chaviva hi ad ma'od)

Tags: chanuka, rambam, reward-punishment

[The Rambam writes in Hilchos Channukah Perek 4 Halacha 12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2850)

> מצות נר חנוכה מצוה חביבה היא עד מאד

The Mitzvah of Ner Channukah is very "chaviv"/"dear" mitzva (please correct this translation.) What is the "p'shat" in the Rambam in this. What cause him (al pi p'shat) or based on what source in the Chazal to write this?

The [Maggid Mishneh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=99676&rid=2850) there refers to the gemorah in Shabbos,

> מצות חנוכה וכו'. שם (דף כ"ג:) אמר רב הונא הרגיל בנר חנוכה הויין לו בנים ת"ח

Does he mean to say that this is the reason why the Rambam says this is a very "chaviv" mitzvah? Is it because of that scar (reward) that one could get for doing this mitzvah that it becomes chaviv?

To clarify. What is p'shat in the Rambam, where does he get this from. Is the Maggid Mishneh coming to explain why it's chaviv is because of the scar or does he mean something else.

Comment: I think chaviv just means people like to do it. Like in purim people are assumed to listen closely to the megillah because they enjoy hearing a good story.